# How to create microsoft app password using API?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm able to create app id using Graph API but app secret/password is not generated with it. I need a way to generate/set a password using APIs.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the password via Azure AD Graph API, you can test it in the [AAD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/#).

**My test sample:**

Request URL:

```
PATCH https://graph.windows.net/{tenant id}/applications/{application object id}?api-version=1.6
```

Request body:

```
{
    "passwordCredentials": [{
        "endDate": "2020-08-12T02:54:44.2530506Z",
        "keyId": "77fe4bf5-5d04-4a62-abc2-f064a9213d3f",
        "startDate": "2019-08-12T02:54:44.2530506Z",
        "customKeyIdentifier": "dGVzdA==",
        "value": "XnkNIsT+cScOYeYJayQ4WNmp9tgAqw5z773uI9WQtAw="
    }]
}
```

For more details about the request body, refer to this link - [PasswordCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#passwordcredential-type).

**Note**: In the AAD Graph Explorer, when you send the request, the progress bar will never finish, but actually it works, you could check the result in the portal -> `Azure Active Directory` after a while.

**Besides**, there is also a `Beta` api in Microsoft Graph - [Update application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0), I have not tested it, so I am not sure if it works. It is a `Beta` version, even if it works, I don't recommend you to use it in the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you following the correct API link?

**[`Create User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)**

It is easy to create Azure AD users using the Microsoft Graph REST. Here is a code sample for your reference:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users 
Authorization: Bearer {token}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "Sajee",
  "mailNickname": "Sinna",
  "userPrincipalName": "upn-value@tenant-value.onmicrosoft.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "password-value"
  }
}
```