# Setting Custom Attributes never completes

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

While following [this article](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/azure-ad-custom-attributes-and-optional-claims-from-an-asp-dot-net-application/), when I try and use Azure AD Graph Explorer to set the value of a custom attribute for a given user, the operation never completes (the top progress bar never reaches the end).

I am an Azure admin (and was able to successfully create the extension just before). I tried with two different users on AAD. Also, If I use a non-existing user OR an invalid extension I quickly get an error as expected, so I believe the settings are correct.

Anyone have any idea what I could be missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this situation many times, not just for this API, it is a known issue of AAD Graph Explorer, but actually the request will work, just ignore it, you can check the result after a while.

[A recent case with this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441904/how-to-create-microsoft-app-password-using-api/57455592#57455592) I encountered, I mentioned it in the `Note` section in my answer.

Comment: This is a known issue in just AAD Graph Explorer.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate your help!